# Add value to input with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a PHP, which loads data from a file WordPress Post.
Then using jQuery,send PHP variables to a `<input>`.
A total of three variables: title, link and content.
Title and link work correctly, but not content.
I guess that's tags, try to eliminate them and get plain text,
But it does not work.

This is the file:

```
<?php
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
?>

<?php
$Id = $_GET['ids'];

$content_post = get_post($Id);
$title = $content_post->post_title;
$content = strip_tags(apply_filters('the_content',$content_post->post_content));
$enlace = post_permalink( $Id );
?>
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><b><i class="indicator flaticon-close33"></i></b></button>
    <p class="enviar-nota">Enviar nota</p>
    <?php echo '<h4 class="verde">' . $title . '</h4>'; ?>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="1998" title="Enviar notas single"]'); ?>

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var titulos = '<?php echo $title; ?>';
        $('#titulo').val(titulos);

    var enlaces = '<?php echo $enlace; ?>';         
    $('#enlace').val(enlaces);

        var textos = '<?php echo $content;  ?>';
        $('#texto').val(textos);

    });
</script>
```

If you deleted these two lines

```
var textos = '<?php echo $content;  ?>';
    $('#texto').val(textos);
```

It is working properly.

The problem is that the first paragraph of the content in WP contains the  and  tags and that is what is causing the problem. 
Thats what i think.

This is the jQuery result:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var titulos = 'Nuevo financiamiento para la compra de cosechadoras CLAAS';
        $('#titulo').val(titulos);

    var enlaces = 'http://saviacomunicacion.com.ar/test2014/sala_de_prensa/nuevo-financiamiento-para-la-compra-de-cosechadoras-claas/';         
    $('#enlace').val(enlaces);

        var textos = 'CLAAS Argentina lanzó una línea de financiamiento para los modelos de cosechadoras TUCANO 470 y TUCANO 460.
Con más de 75 años fabricando cosechadoras, CLAAS lanza en Argentina una nueva línea de financiamiento propio para la adquisición de dos modelos de sus cosechadoras TUCANO.
Federico Sánchez, gerente comercial de CLAAS Argentina, explicó que: “la metodología es muy simple, se presenta una carpeta a la empresa, se analiza la situación de cada cliente y una vez aprobada, abonando el 15% del valor de la cosechadora, se accede al financiamiento y a la cosechadora.”
La línea de crédito involucra a los modelos TUCANO 460 y TUCANO 470, dos equipos de porte medio que cuentan con la máxima tecnología en cosecha disponible en sus hermanas mayores, las LEXION.
La propuesta de CLAAS Argentina otorga un plazo a pagar en cuatro campañas agrícolas, con dos modalidades distintas de acuerdo a si el cliente realiza entrega de equipos usados o no.
Este financiamiento tiene como fin darles una herramienta más de acceso a la última tecnología en cosecha a los productores y contratistas. “Hace cuatro años que no teníamos una herramienta financiera propia. Contar ahora con ella nos ubica mucho más cerca de nuestros clientes y de todos los que buscan actualizarse tecnológicamente con equipamiento de primer nivel”.
La línea de cosechadoras TUCANO ofrece la misma tecnología que sus hermanas mayores en un envase más pequeño, liviano y conveniente para las condiciones de muchas regiones del país.
';
    $('#texto').val(textos);    
    });
</script>
```

In the Google Chrome Inspector the first line display in red

> var textos = 'CLAAS Argentina lanzó una línea de financiamiento para
>   los modelos de cosechadoras TUCANO 470 y TUCANO 460.

The rest in black.

Comment: why dnt you sent the data as json statement

Comment: I don´t know how to do what you say. I solved the problem with the Machavity solution. **var textos = '<?php echo str_replace("\n", '', addslashes($content))  ?>';**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JS is vary particular about how you put strings in. I always recommend you add slashes and remove the line breaks. In your case slashes aren't the problem but if this is some value that can users can edit it could be

```
var textos = '<?php echo str_replace("\n", '', addslashes($content))  ?>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line breaks, like this:

```
var textos = 'CLAAS Argentina lanzó una línea de financiamiento para los modelos de cosechadoras TUCANO 470 y TUCANO 460.Con más de 75 años fabricando cosechadoras, CLAAS lanza en Argentina una nueva línea de financiamiento propio para la adquisición de dos modelos de sus cosechadoras TUCANO.Federico Sánchez, gerente comercial de CLAAS Argentina, explicó que: “la metodología es muy simple, se presenta una carpeta a la empresa, se analiza la situación de cada cliente y una vez aprobada, abonando el 15% del valor de la cosechadora, se accede al financiamiento y a la cosechadora.”La línea de crédito involucra a los modelos TUCANO 460 y TUCANO 470, dos equipos de porte medio que cuentan con la máxima tecnología en cosecha disponible en sus hermanas mayores, las LEXION.La propuesta de CLAAS Argentina otorga un plazo a pagar en cuatro campañas agrícolas, con dos modalidades distintas de acuerdo a si el cliente realiza entrega de equipos usados o no.Este financiamiento tiene como fin darles una herramienta más de acceso a la última tecnología en cosecha a los productores y contratistas. “Hace cuatro años que no teníamos una herramienta financiera propia. Contar ahora con ella nos ubica mucho más cerca de nuestros clientes y de todos los que buscan actualizarse tecnológicamente con equipamiento de primer nivel”.La línea de cosechadoras TUCANO ofrece la misma tecnología que sus hermanas mayores en un envase más pequeño, liviano y conveniente para las condiciones de muchas regiones del país.';
```

Comment: The text is loaded dynamically, so you can not remove the line breaks manually. Thanks anyway